# Convert decimal number to string like \uxxxx in Python

Tags: python

I have decimal number based on len of string. How to convert it to \u0030 (with 0030 4 digits is len of string)?

Example:

```
char = 'teststring'
```

have 10 characters

then convert to

```
u'\u0010teststring'
```

I used for

```
char = char.encode('utf-16le')
```

Comment: I have decimal number based on len of string. How to convert it to \u0030 (with 0030 4 digits is len of string) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`unichr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#unichr).

```
>>> unichr(10)
u'\n'
>>> u'\u000a'
u'\n'
```